# Loading a file into a C++ object from an iOS App / issues with <iostream> on iOS

Tags: c++, ios, swift, iostream, objective-c++

I'm working on integrating a C++ library (the [GRT](https://github.com/nickgillian/grt), a machine learning toolkit, to be specific) inside of an iOS app.

I've built the GRT as a framework, including using some Objective-C++ wrapper functions to call between my app and the framework.

At the moment, I'm trying to troubleshoot something involving file loading. Specifically, I'm trying to load a file from my app bundle into a GRT module.

Here's where I get the file I want access to, and initialize the GRT wrapper:

```
func loadTrainingData(){

    let documentsUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let fileUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("train.grt")

    let pipeline = GestureRecognitionPipeline()
    let test:Bool = pipeline.load(fileUrl.path)
    print(test)
}
```

And here's the Obj-C++ wrapper code that's called when `pipeline.load` is called:

```
- (BOOL)load:(NSString *) path
{
    BOOL result = self.instance->load(std::string(path.UTF8String));

    if (result) {
        std::cout << "GRT config";
        std::cout << self.instance->getModelAsString();
        std::cout << "GRT info: " << self.instance->getInfo();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Finally, here's the actual C++ code that's part of the GRT library, where file loading is handled:

```
bool GestureRecognitionPipeline::load(const std::string &filename){

    std::fstream file;        

    //Clear any previous setup
    clear();

    file.open(filename.c_str(), std::iostream::in );

    if( !file.is_open() ){
        errorLog << __GRT_LOG__ << " Failed to open file with filename: " << filename << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    ...
 }
```

Currently, I'm always failing to have my pipeline object successfully import a file. I don't think it's necessarily something to do with the way I'm accessing the file on the iOS side (though, I could be wrong). Does anyone have any insight? Any appreciated - thanks!

**EDIT**: I was able to verify that I am loading my file is being loaded properly by this check:

`let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "acc-orientation", ofType: "grt")
        print(path as Any!)`

But, I'm still getting the same issues as before.

**EDIT 2** I verified that the path is being loaded correctly in the the Obj-C++ wrapper too; which leads me to think it may be something related to the way that  is handled in iOS....totally lost here now...

**EDIT 3** As suggested by a colleague, I tried using the `absoluteString` of the file url to pass to my wrapper and the underlying C++ code, since the C++ doesn't have access to the sandboxed environment of iOS. Still the same result:

```
let documentsUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]

let fileUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("acc-orientation.grt")

let pipeline = GestureRecognitionPipeline()
let test:Bool = pipeline.load(fileUrl.absoluteString)
```

**EDIT 4** As suggested in the comments, I tried using `fileSystemRepresentation`, but this also didn't bring success.

```
- (BOOL)load:(NSURL *) url {

    BOOL result = self.instance->load(std::string([url fileSystemRepresentation]));
   ...
}
```

**EDIT 5:** I made a simple test project that attempts to only access the file and load it using Swift->Obj-C++->C++ (no framework files, in other words). Here's a [link where it can be downloaded](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c162qofwx6qj2yw/TextFileInputTest.zip?dl=0). Any help appreciated!

Comment: Who says C++ code doesn't have access to your sandbox? It's part of the application, it has access. It doesn't have access to anything _outside_, just like none of your Swift code.

Comment: @gnasher729 Makes sense; I may have misunderstood / misspoke when I typed that.

Comment: You should use `fileSystemRepresentation` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1414559-filesystemrepresentation) to convert a path from `NSString` into a c string.

Comment: @macmoonshine I updated the question (still the same results, though)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are almost there. I have downloaded your sample project and got it working. Your problem has to do with the actual location of the file you want to open. At the moment you are trying to open the file from the Documents folder but you never actually copy the file from the App Bundle to the Documents folder. So there are two solutions:

**Solution 1: App Bundle**

Alter the `loadTrainingData` method in `ViewController.swift` to access the file from the App Bundle:

```
func loadTrainingData(){
    let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "acc-orientation", withExtension: "grt")
    let wrapper = Wrapper()
    let test:Bool = wrapper.load(path)
    print(test)
}
```

**Solution 2: Documents folder**

Copy the file from your App Bundle to your Documents folder right after the first launch. Therefore, copy the following code snippet to your `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    do {
        let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("acc-orientation.grt")
        let bundleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "acc-orientation", withExtension: "grt")
        try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: bundleURL!, to: url)
    } catch {
        print("File already exists")
    }
    return true
}
```

With either of these solutions your `FileLoader::load` method will return `true`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey Jens, thank you for this - this works perfectly for my example project, but when trying it out with the compiled framework project (my original one), where I'm passing the file to a class in the framework; I still seem to be getting errors - would you mind taking a look at that if I upload it?

Comment: Sure, upload it and I'll have a look.

Comment: Here it is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/46qkuflzbmoou0c/GRT-iOS-HelloWorld.zip?dl=0

Thank you SO much!

Comment: Well, the problem is not the file loading anymore. That one works with the aforementioned solutions. Seems like the format of you file is wrong. Check line 2326 in `GestureRecognitionPipeline.cpp`. It expects a header of `GRT_PIPELINE_FILE_V3.0` but your file comes with a header of `GRT_LABELLED_CLASSIFICATION_DATA_FILE_V1.0`.

Comment: Yup, that's it - thank you so much; really appreciate the help, Jens!